# Difference between IsEmailUserName , UserNameAttribute and EnableEmailUserName

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm following this doc to configure email as username in wso2is 5.2.0

https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Using+Email+Address+as+the+Username

I have enabled EnableEmailUserName in carbon.xml and added UserNameAttribute = mail in the jdbc store, also I found that there is an attribute IsEmailUserName in the jdbc store that is not talked about in the doc ?

Should I leave it as false per default or should I set it to true ?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches for enabling email username in WSO2 servers.

**Approach 1.**

If following property is configured in carbon.xml file

`<EnableEmailUserName>true</EnableEmailUserName>`

Then,

```
If user in the super tenant can login with email attribute –> bob@wso2.com
If user in the super tenant can login with any other attribute –> bob
If user in the “foo” tenant can login with email attribute –> alice@wso2.com@foo.com
If user in the “foo” tenant can login with any other attribute –> CAN NOT
```

Then, all tenant users must use email as their user name. If any tenant user uses some other user name, tenant users would always be dispatched to super tenant domain. So, you can not use any other attribute to login when email user name (in carbon.xml file) has been enabled.

**Approach 2.**

Without configuring Email User name property in carbon.xml.

Then,

```
If user in the super tenant can login with email attribute –> bob@wso2.com@carbon.super
If user in the super tenant can login with any other attribute –> bob
If user in the “foo” tenant can login with email attribute –> alice@wso2.com@foo.com
If user in the “foo” tenant can login with any other attribute –> alice@foo.com
```

User who has email in super tenant domain must login with by appending the super tenant domain ( “@carbon.super”) name in to user’s email.

You can find more information in [1].

[1] http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/10/07/email-username-with-identity-server/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to configure IsEmailUserName property. This property is no longer used in Identity Server 5.2.0

Thanks
Isura